# Is it OK to override a Set's contains() method?

Tags: java, reflection, collections

I was playing around with Java reflection, and I wanted to create a method caching mechanism from Methods declared in different classes. In order to prevent random behavior, I want to forbid loading methods with the same signature to the Cache (method declared in different classes can have the same signature).

The only way I found of doing this, was to Override the contains() method of the Set where I cache the methods.

Is it dangerous to do so? Do you have any better idea to achieve this?

```
private final Set<Method> methodsCache;

public MyMethodCachingClass(Set<Class<?>> classes) {
    methodsCache = new HashSet<Method>(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1467698582662452923L;

        /**
        * Overwriting the contains method of this Set so that we don't allow multiple methods with the same signature,
        * even if they are declared in different classes.
        */
        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof Method)) {
                return false;
            }

            Method method = (Method) o;
            for (Method m : this) {
                if (method.getName().equals(m.getName()) && method.getParameterTypes().equals(m.getParameterTypes())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    for (Class<?> c : classes) {
        for (Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (methodsCache.contains(m)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The method " + m.getName() + " exists with the same signature in two different classes.");
            }
            methodsCache.add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You really only want to cache one version of a method, regardless of the class it's declared in? That seems like an odd requirement...

Comment: @ig0774: I don't have any requirements, I'm just playing around. But it doesn't seem that odd to me, what if you have a web servlet that should execute a method on your web server? You might want to be able to declare the executable methods in different classes to increase code readability, and you certainly don't want your client to have to worry about where you declared the method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a combination of the following for your cache key:

class name + method name + method parameter types

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. What if I want to be able to able to call a method without knowing which class it is declared in?

Comment: then you use only method name + method parameter types

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely okay to override the "contains()" method - however, it is generally unnecessary.  The purpose of the contains() method is simply to check wether an equivalent object already exists in the collection.

The "equals" method for your particular object collection will be used to ascertain this.

However, if you want custom behavior for contains which CANNOT be embedded in the object, it might be worthwhile to hack the contains() method. I think , given the fact that you are trying to cache java Methods, you might want to glue the "contains" logic into the set containing these methods.... However, its not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above post (@jayunit100). However, I wouldn't override contains() for this. Instead, I'd write an implementation of Comparator and use a SortedSet. Eg:

```
SortedSet<Method> cachedMethods = new TreeSet<Method>(new Comparator<Method>() {
    // compare() implementation omitted
});
```

Comment: I think the Comparator is designed to compare elements based on their intrinsic property. The time of insertion is not an intrinsic property. Therefore, I don't think it is possible to build a Comparator that respects the order of insertion without breaking the invariant `a.compareTo(b) > 0 is equivalent to b.compareTo(a) < 0`. So even if a comparator that would always return `1` might work, I don't think it is preferable.

Comment: I think you're getting confused with `Comparable`. `Comparable` is for objects that _naturally ordered_ (ie intrinsic order), whereas `Comparator` is used (generally) to apply some non-natural order. 

The crux of your problem is that you want compare two `Method`s and say that they are equivalent. For this, I'd use a `Comparator` rather than overriding `contains()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was talking about a different problem, my bad. But my point is still valid though. Creating a Comparator that returns 0 if two objects are not considered equals (which would be the case here) is said to be `inconsistent with equals`, and this is not recommended as it will make the Set behave strangely, as described here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Hi Nabarraille, I completely agree. Please understand that your Method comparison is inconsistent with `equals()`, and that overriding `contains()` doesn't provide much benefit. You'll need to override a number of other `Set` methods to keep your `Set` in a consistent state (eg `remove()`).